# How do I set the size of a JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextarea

I'm fairly new to working with graphics in Java, and have been trying to make a simple console to display text based games in a window. I have a test class, where I'm working on the console, but when I add a JTextArea to my console window, it either takes up the entire window or doesn't display at all.

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.Event;
public class GUI {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("AoA");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(1020,760);
        frame.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        JTextArea jta = new JTextArea(100,100);
        jta.setEditable(false);
        jta.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frame.add(jta);

    }
}
```

I know that some of my imports aren't used in this file, but they will used in the final game. I am also aware that the JTextArea is set to size 100,100, which I am unsure whether it is too large or small. I could really use some help on this, though.

Comment: *JTextArea jta = new JTextArea(100,100);* - the (100, 100) means columns/row, not pixels. Typically you would use something like: (40, 10) and then add the text area to a JScrollPane. The text area would then be size to display about 40 "W" characters on a line with 10 lines. If more lines are required, the scrollbar will appear. *it either takes up the entire window* - why is that a problem? You only add a single component to the frame.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is the installed by default `BorderLayout` in your frame. The easiest way to solve your problem is to set another layout manager.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(GUI::startUp); 
}

private static void startUp() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("AoA");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1020,760);
    frame.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); // FlowLayout is required
    JTextArea jta = new JTextArea(40,40);
    jta.setEditable(false);
    jta.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    // JScrollPane to get the scroll bars when required
    frame.add(new JScrollPane(jta));
    // setVisible should be last operation to get a correct painting
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Please take a look for [layout managers in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)